# Recover a NAS hard drive

Tags: data-recovery, nas, sata

My NAS hard drive died today and I want to recover its data by connect it to a PC, how can I do it with Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "died". Connect the drive, run `dmesg -T` to see what the system thinks, where/if the drive is mounted.  `sudo fdisk -l` will give you more information. `gparted` is a powerful disk destruction/recovery tool.